# Crystal reports group data by floating hours

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

For example, i have SQL table with structure shown below. `RASP_DATE` means time when train departs, `RACE_HOURS` means how much train travels in hours.

```
RASP_DATE                  RACE_HOURS
01.10.2020 15:05:00        4
01.10.2020 15:35:00        3
01.10.2020 16:10:00        8
01.10.2020 16:25:00        6
```

I need to develop a report based on this data, to calculate the total travel time every hour. For example, according to the example above, the report will show that from 15:00 to 16:00 the total travel time is 7 hours, from 16:00 to 17:00 - 14 hours. This task is easily accomplished using groups in Crystal Reports. However, the task is different - i need to calculate the number of hours of travel in a "running" hour. The user enters the parameter "minutes" (for example, 15), which is a multiple of 5, and now the "hours" should be calculated not from 15:00 to 16:00, but from 15:15 to 16:15, from 17:15 to 18:15, etc. Most likely, it is nessesary to change the grouping for this, but I don't know exactly a formula or how to do this. Please give me a hint.

Comment: For hint - create a formula, calculating hour of rasp_date minus X minutes and group by formula result.

Comment: Can you please concretisize - to create formula in groups? And how to do it in CR syntax, or where to read about it?

Comment: Just create normal formula field and use it for grouping. Sorry, I have no time create a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this:

1. Created new operator "minutes" (number).
2. Created new formula "floating_hour":

   ```
   if minute({TableName.RASP_DATE}) < {?minutes} then
   time(hour({TableName.RASP_DATE})-1,{?minutes},0) else
   if minute({TableName.RASP_DATE}) >= {?minutes} then
   time(hour({TableName.RASP_DATE}),{?minutes},0)
   ```
3. Created a group by "RASP_DATE" (Order by weeks)
4. Created a group by "floating_hour" formula.
5. Summarized RACE_HOURS in the "floating_hours" group.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but try something like below. Please notice that if RASP_DATE can contain seconds, the formulas might be adjusted.

1. Create a formula called "hour"

   hour({TableName.RASP_DATE})
2. Create a formula called "fraction"

   minute({TableName.RASP_DATE}) \ {?minutes} //the operatior is an integer division
3. Create a group by "hour" formula
4. Create a group by "fraction" formula
5. Put a summary field in the group to sum the RACE_HOURS.

I think this gives a direction to get to the full solution.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this and tell about my results.

Comment: It doesn't quite work like this. But it gave me idea, i will write it there, so thank you again.